# SharePoint Keywords - Not pulling information from Manage Keywords?

Tags: search

I've read that SharePoint should be pulling the keywords from the Manage Keywords list?

For some reason, mine is not doing that? As you can see in the images below the Manage Keywords has content. But the list for the Service Desk is empty?

[alt text http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/604/managekeywords.png](http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/604/managekeywords.png)

[alt text http://img375.imageshack.us/img375/685/keywordslist.png](http://img375.imageshack.us/img375/685/keywordslist.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I figured it out this morning after reading your post. The 2010 feature is intriguing, but to add the keywords for the help desk, you have to use the "View all site content" at the help desk site, then you will see a keywords list. Once content is added there, it will show up in the keywords column while editing the items.

Thanks for looking into this :-)

Answer (score 2):

The 'manage keywords' feature is used for best bet results for search. As far as I know there are no default SharePoint site columns that display these keywords (and the default 'keywords' site column is a multi line text). Could what you have read refer to the SharePoint 2010 Managed Metadata 'Keywords' feature. This pulls in keywords from the managed metadata service as options in a site column but this feature is not available in SharePoint 2007.